# What formats does ContentService support?

Tags: google-apps-script

The documentation for [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_contentservice) provides some example formats. I assume that the reason why pdf is not among them is because it is not supported. Please, confirm.

Answer (score 0):

It supports JSON, RSS, plain text, ATOM, XML.